# Are JavaScript frameworks web frameworks?

Tags: javascript, web

AFAIK, the web has three components:

- HTTP: Application protocol (more than transport)
- HyperText: HTML or other format with links
- URL: Embedded in the hypertext for next allowed state transfers

Do JavaScript frameworks adhere to this flow? I ask because I'm curious why a document like [ROCA](http://roca-style.org/) is even needed.

Comment: Not voting to close because I think this falls under ["Good Subjective"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) but since I see a close vote at this point in time, it's fair to say this may be toeing the line of [subjective questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). I don't know enough about the topic to say whether or not this question [has an answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/), but if it IS closed, it's likely to be because users think it's too subjective. Just a heads up.

Comment: @rockerest The are four possible answers: a) yes; b) no; c) some are, some aren't; d) your definition of web is incorrect.

Comment: @rockerest I've given a very clear definition, it's not subjective.

Comment: e) What exactly is "the web", what exactly are "web frameworks"?

Comment: @torazaburo client-side

Comment: @deceze I gave a clear definition of the web. A web framework helps you implement it.

Comment: @torazaburo they don't need to cover the back end, they just need to interact with the backend in the way I described.

Comment: @torazaburo are js front-end frameworks *web* front-end frameworks

Comment: @MaxToro, Your responses to me seemed hostile and defensive, but I'll chalk that up to it being text on the internet. In your comments, you define two very strong reasons this would be considered subjective: disagreements about the fundamental nature of what the web is, and disagreements about what is and what is not a "web framework". I'm not casting a vote here because I don't need to, but I think if you objectively digest the things you've written yourself, you might see the perspective that feels this isn't the right medium for this question. Sorry what I wrote seemed to anger you.

Comment: @rockerest If I have an incorrect idea of what *web* and *web framework* is, then that would be a valid answer. It does not make it subjective, Is the web a subjective thing?

Comment: @rockerest "The World Wide Web (www) is an information space where documents and other web resources are identified by URLs, interlinked by hypertext links, and can be accessed via the Internet." - Wikipedia

Comment: @MaxToro Thanks. You seem like you have a really solid grasp of English, so it's weird that I should need to post this: "
condescending
[kon-duh-sen-ding]

adjective
1.
showing or implying a usually patronizing descent from dignity or superiority" - reference.com